# How to include *.so file in makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

For a program I was linking the static glibc library (which I modified). My makefile looks something like this.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFILES = main.c

CXXFLAGS = -g -o prog -D_GNU_SOURCE
LIBS = ../../nptl/libpthread.a ../../libc.a -lpthread

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFILES) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)
```

However, instead of using the static *.a files, I now want to use the dynamic shared object *.so files. Is it enough to replace the *.a files by *.so files in the makefile. If not what is the correct way of doing so. I tried to simply replace the *.a with *.so files in the makefile, but it seems like when I do that the program uses the original glibc (rather than my modified one).

Comment: Don't you just need to compile as normal, and then set your `LD_PRELOAD` before you run?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: No I don't want to use LD_PRELOAD!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html. It should help you out.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: In which case, you should edit your question so that it details all of your constraints.

Comment: Read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use the standard libraries, you might need the `-nostdlib` flag.  In addition, if you want to dynamically link libraries, you need to tell the linker where they are.  `-L/dir/containing -lc`.

If you don't want to set a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when executing, you'll need to set `rpath`, `-Wl,--rpath=/path/containing`.

Comment: Points for pointing out what `--rpath` does. So that's why so many projects I've downloaded require `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in their build.